# Use a casted column name in a join query in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a query like that casts an xml query

```
SELECT TOP 5
  CAST (row.query('col(/xml/tag)'), as NVARCHAR(100)) AS 'foobar'
FROM db.table
```

How can I use the casted result of the xml query in a `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT TOP 5
  CAST (row.query('col(/xml/tag)'), as NVARCHAR(100)) AS 'foobar'
FROM db.table
LEFT JOIN db.table_table
-- don't know the syntax for this part
ON db.table['foobar'] = db.table_table.col
```

Comment: This needs [Dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: @JohnHC thanks for the docs, appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the original query as `sub-select`

```
SELECT foobar
FROM   (SELECT TOP 5 Cast (row.query('col(/xml/tag)') AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS foobar
        FROM   db.TABLE) t
       LEFT JOIN db.table_table
              ON t.foobar = db.table_table.col
```